# Difference between CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME and PROJECT_NAME?

Tags: cmake

What is the difference between CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME and PROJECT_NAME?

From the documentation:

[CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME.html)

> The name of the current project.
>
> This specifies name of the current project from the closest inherited project() command.

[PROJECT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/PROJECT_NAME.html)

> Name of the project given to the project command.
>
> This is the name given to the most recent project() command.

I don't understand the difference.

When should I use `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME`? When should I use `PROJECT_NAME`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From the documentation, I don't get the difference between the two variables.

The difference is that `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME` is the name from the last `project` call from the root CMakeLists.txt, while `PROJECT_NAME` is from the last `project` call, regardless from the location of the file containing the command.

The difference is recognizable from the following test.

File structure:

```
|-CMakeLists.txt
\-test2
  |-CMakeLists.txt
  \-test3
    \-CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(A)
message("< ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} / ${PROJECT_NAME}")
project(B)
message("< ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} / ${PROJECT_NAME}")
add_subdirectory(test2)
message("< ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} / ${PROJECT_NAME}")
project(C)
message("< ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} / ${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

test2/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(D)
message("<< ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} / ${PROJECT_NAME}")
add_subdirectory(test3)
project(E)
message("<< ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} / ${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

test2/test3/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(F)
message("<<< ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} / ${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

The relevant output is:

> ```
> < A / A
> < B / B
> << B / D
> <<< B / F
> << B / E
> < B / B
> < C / C
> ```

In the sub-directories, always B is the value for `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME`.

Answer (score 6):

It may help, if we look at it this way: `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME` is a `global` and `PROJECT_NAME` is a `local` name ;)